# CMake add external libraries located within the project folder

Tags: c++, cmake

Preface: I am on Windows and wish to easily send this project to someone else on a different OS.

My folder structure is:

```
EigenTest/
libs/
├─ Eigen3/
├─ OpenBLAS C Asm/
src/
├─ main.cpp
```

My cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(EigenTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(EigenTest src/main.cpp)

add_library(EigenLib STATIC)

target_include_directories(EigenLib INTERFACE "libs/Eigen3")

target_link_libraries(EigenTest PRIVATE EigenLib)

add_library(OpenBlasLib STATIC)

target_include_directories(OpenBlasLib PRIVATE "libs/OpenBLAS C ASM")

target_link_libraries(EigenTest PRIVATE OpenBlasLib)
```

For some reason, I get an error that there are no sources when both Eigen3 and OpenBLAS have their own CmakeList.txt and source files in those folders.
Error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: EigenLib


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: OpenBlasLib
```

Comment: Replace `add_library(EigenLib STATIC)` with `add_subdirectory(libs/Eigen3)`

Comment: Won't that make Eigen3 available to all files and might cause hidden dependency? I am a beginner and trying to follow the advice to use target_ Cmake functions to avoid that  (in the event I add more files/libraries)

Comment: add_library adds a build target, but libs/Eigen3/CMakeLists.txt adds that target and add_subdirectory must be used.

Comment: Eigen is not a static library. If you wanted to define your own target for eigen, it would need to be a `INTERFACE` library with probably the only information about the include dir attached. As for `add_library`: Since you're probably working with MSVC on windows, you could think of `add_subdirectory` as making every target from the project described by the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the directory you pass as parameter available in the project containing the `add_library` command...